# Weird characters from contact page

Tags: captcha

We've just recreated a contact form on a HTML webpage. We've implemented Google reCaptcha to prevents bots and spammers from abusing the form.

We've received some feedback from our client, saying they receive a lot of mails with following content:

```
Language:     French
Name:         cmRDCjlVlGjMOQxWcAB
Street + nr:  nXlomEXzzHz
Town:         EDMkWfRUIFD
Tel:          UaRrOnVFboDiWeBIAI
Message:      HghmAy fsyobphashrh,
              [url=http://bojrsarqnphy.com/]bojrsarqnphy[/url],
              [link=http://mqimyniomejg.com/]mqimyniomejg[/link],
              http://faqwpyfhosll.com/
```

We've also had instances where nothing was entered, except for the language (which is a static feature, depending on what page they fill in the form). This is weird, as at least 2 input field have the required attribute.

My questions:

1. Can they work around reCaptcha (possibly with some sort of injection)?
2. Same as above, but for 'required' attribute in HTML?

**Edit**

I'll try to explain in more detail. The CAPTCHA system is the only check for form input. As you can see in the example above, it's a simple contact form. When pressing submit, I'm first validating some fields that are tagged required (Name and email) + validate the format of the email address. After that, the CAPTCHA input is validated. When that input is approved, it forwards from my `contact.html` file to `thankyou.php`. On that file, it strips the content from the controls and emails that to the mail address set in a variable on that page. That user then sees a message thanking them.

Our problem is weird input (See example) or sometimes no input (which would be impossible because of the required tags on some field).

What I'm asking if is there's anyone who sees a flaw in the design, recognizes this problem and can suggest steps to take to prevent the behavior described above.

Comment: What does a mail received by your client have anything to do with captcha?

Comment: You're probably right.  [Bots are better at solving CAPTCHAs (even ReCAPTCHA) than humans are these days](http://www.webroot.com/blog/2014/01/21/googles-recaptcha-automatic-fire-newly-launched-recaptcha-solving-breaking-service/).  And bots don't have to be anywhere near as good as humans to make it economical if there's no rate-limiting in place.

Comment: I've clarified my question. Is there a reason it's still on hold?

Comment: The HTML5 "required" attribute is a client-side control. Browsers more than a couple of years old don't have it at all. No spam bot will ever implement it. You should enforce field validation in the target PHP script (which, if I understand correctly, is `thankyou.php`).  It might help if you included the code from `thankyou.php` in your question.

Comment: That validation of the form fields you're doing before "forwarding" to `thankyou.php`, is that done using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please be reminded, Captcha is used for preventing bot automated submission.

I see the *spam* details are like random words, and I don't think this is an exploitation code or spam ads.

I would suggest you to have a research on Captcha, especially the new Captcha released by Google. Captcha in security is kinda chasing game. You build a Captcha system, the hacker crack it and *profit*. Thus, you can try on using some strong Captcha and renewing/updating the Captcha system upon the efficiency of the Captcha.

However, in most of the websites I know, they are using some kind of checking system(some use AI, some use spam check) to detect spam messages, if this is a comment site then you can try some good spam-control systems like Discuq. If this is a email or contact form, you can try the spam-control on your email system.

For your question 2, do you mean the validation of inputs?

(*sorry for my bad english :P)

Comment: Thank you for a constructive response. I'm using reCaptcha from Google. I'm not sure what to think of the input that is send, the only thing I can think of is an exotic writing (cyrillic or some kind) which was converted to roman writing.

The second question is about the validation indeed. Maybe this is not exactly the right place to ask this question, but as I sometimes get blank input, the validation is put in place to prevent that. 

I'm not sure if the validation and the fact that we get a lot of Jibberish input have something in common. Any hints/direction are/is welcome.